# how to add two different array in to simple for each loop

Tags: php, google-analytics

Hello Friend my Question is Quite simple but difficult to understand I think so.

Here is some more code :-

```
    $graph1 = new gapi($ga_email,$ga_password);

    $dimensions = array('date');
    $metrics    = array('visits');

    $graph1->requestReportData($ga_profile_id,
                           $dimensions,
                           $metrics,
                            'date'
                           );


$graph2 = new gapi($ga_email,$ga_password);

$dimensions = array('date');
$metrics    = array('visits');

$graph2->requestReportData($ga_profile_id,
                       $dimensions,
                       $metrics,
                       'date',
                       $filter, // Filter the data
                       '2012-09-07', // Start Date
                       '2012-10-07', // End Date
                       1,  // Start Index
                       500 // Max results

                       );
```

I have an array lets say

```
 $resultsg1 = $graph1->getResults();
```

and

```
 $resultsg2 = $graph2->getResults();
```

and I am trying to fetch this value from for each loop code is here

```
data.addRows([
          <?php
          foreach($results as $result)
         {
            echo '["'.date("l, F j, Y",strtotime($result->getDate())).'", '.$result->getVisits().'," Visits :'.$result->getVisits().'","'.date("l, F j, Y",strtotime($result->getDate())).'",'.$result->getVisits().'," Visits :'.$result->getVisits().'"],';
          }

          ?>
         ]);
```

Now My Question I need an output something like this :-

```
foreach($resultsg1 as $result1 and resultsg2 as $results2 )

 {
                echo '["'.date("l, F j, Y",strtotime($result1->getDate())).'", '.$result1->getVisits().'," Visits :'.$result1->getVisits().'","'.date("l, F j, Y",strtotime($result2->getDate())).'",'.$result2->getVisits().'," Visits :'.$result2->getVisits().'"],';
              }

              ?>
             ]);
```

Any help is highly appreciated.... :)

**Note**:- Purpose of this code is to simply create a graph with two different months.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [SPL](http://docs.php.net/book.spl)'s [MultipleIterator](http://docs.php.net/class.multipleiterator)

```
<?php
echo 'phpversion: ', phpversion(), "\n";
$resultsg1 = data(1);
$resultsg2 = data(2);
$iterator = new MultipleIterator();
$iterator->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($resultsg1));
$iterator->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($resultsg2));

foreach( $iterator as $e ) {
    echo 'r1:', $e[0]->bar(), ', r2:', $e[1]->bar(), "\n";
}

// boilerplate
function data($n) {
    return array_map(function($e) use($n) { return new Foo($n.'-'.$e); }, range(1, 9));
}

class Foo {
    public function __construct($n) {
        $this->n = $n;
    }
    public function bar() {
        return $this->n;
    }
}
```

prints

```
phpversion: 5.4.7
r1:1-1, r2:2-1
r1:1-2, r2:2-2
r1:1-3, r2:2-3
r1:1-4, r2:2-4
r1:1-5, r2:2-5
r1:1-6, r2:2-6
r1:1-7, r2:2-7
r1:1-8, r2:2-8
r1:1-9, r2:2-9
```

Comment: Answer is still the same. my `data(n)` is your `$graphn->getResults()` and instead of calling `$e[n]->foo()` you have to invoke `$e[n]->getDate()`, `->getVisits()` and so on.

Comment: sound good but it seems more complicated to me can you please explain me more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($results1 as $k => $result)
{
     echo $result->getDate() , $results2[$k]->getDate() 
}
```

if not same lenght, need check with isset($results2[$k])

Answer (score 0):

Unsure if I totally understand you requirement but if you have multiple arrays and want to join them together and then loop through them look at array_merge and if more complex structures array merge recursive

```
$results = array_merge($result1, $resultg1);
```

foreach($results as $result)
    ....

Comment: :) I try this but my two different graphs is on occurs in the same line.